# Using managed identities for HTTP linked service

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-explorer

I am working on creating a flow where I get JSON data from a rest api authenticating with the managed identity of my ADF instance and copy the data to a Kusto cluster. To do this, I am following the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http?tabs=data-factory

However, when I go to create a linked service I do not see any way to authenticate against the API using my managed identity: [http linked service auth options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9G4R.jpg)

I was expecting something like the options given in the Web task in ADF, where I am allowed to selected managed identities:[web task auth options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekGzt.jpg)

Comment: You can use **Rest** connector instead of HTTP linked service. Rest connector has **Managed Service Identity** as authentication type

Answer (score 0):

HTTP connector supports only **Anonymous**, **Basic**, **Digest**, **Windows**, and **ClientCertificate** as authentication types. To use Managed Identity authentication type, you can use **Rest** linked service.

- Search for REST in the available list of linked service and select **REST** connector.
  [image]
- You can select Managed Identity as auth type.
  [image]

**Reference:** [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#linked-service-properties) on Data Fcatory - REST connector.